# SQL Server query buildup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set with data in a SQL Server database and I need to calculate uptime of a machine. I'm using two variables to determine uptime or downtime. These two variables are `machine_ON` and `failure(s)`. `machine_ON` is only one variable in the database, `failure` can be 64 different failures, but all indicates as `fx_x`.

The status information of these variables is stored in the database as follow:

```
timestamp                   failurebitNr    timestampOutOfAlarm
2012-01-17 10:38:58.000     f1_14           2012-01-17 10:39:05.000
```

Meaning: failure `f1_14` was active from `2012-01-17 10:38:58.000` until `2012-01-17 10:39:05.000`

Also the `machine_ON` state is saved in the same table on the same way, only the `failurebitNr` has a different value [`t2_13`].

So to determine the uptime, I need to get the timediff between `timestamp` and `timestampOutOfAlarm` where `failurebutNr = 't2_13'` minus any failure time.

So for example I have those rows in my database:

[image: Click for image of table representation]

This should give the following graphical representation:

[image: Graphical representation of the dataser]

Green is uptime, red is downtime.

I'm used to work with PHP and than use a while loop and file some array's and do other scripting. But now I need to do this all in a SQL Server database in query ways...

So, how can I calculate the uptime (green) and downtime (red)?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to get the time in seconds that the machine is ON. I used this query:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
DECLARE @startDate datetime
DECLARE @endDate datetime
DECLARE @projectNr int
DECLARE @MachineNr nvarchar(10) 

SET @startDate = '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @endDate  = '2012-02-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @projectNr = '1234567'
SET @MachineNr = '2'

SELECT 
    DATEDIFF("SECOND",
        CASE WHEN timestamp < @startDate 
            THEN @startDate 
            ELSE timestamp 
        END, 
        CASE WHEN timestampOutOfAlarm > @endDate OR timestampOutOfAlarm IS NULL 
            THEN @endDate
            ELSE timestampOutOfAlarm 
        END) AS Uptime
FROM 
    [table]
WHERE
     timestamp < @endDate
     AND (timestampOutOfAlarm > @startDate OR timestampOutOfAlarm IS NULL)
     AND fileProjectNr = @projectNr
     AND fileProjectMachineNr = @MachineNr
     AND (failureBitNr = 't2_13' AND failureBitValue = '1')
```

Comment: Query added to get the time when the machine is on. Now, how to substract the failure time..?
Because there can be more failures simultaneously, how to determine the failure time, only from start to end, regardless of the amount of failures.

Comment: I think I found a solution for my problem. I need to work this out and when I'm sure it is fine, I will post it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I did it in 2 stored procedures, or Query's. One for getting the "ON" time and one for getting all the "DOWN" time within the "ON" time. Whith those two times I can calculate the uptime, downtime, maintenance time.

Query for ON time:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
SELECT  fctAlarmId,
        fileProjectNr, 
        fileProjectMachineNr, 
        failureBitNr,   
        timestamp, 
        CASE WHEN timestampOutOfAlarm > @endDate OR timestampOutOfAlarm IS NULL 
            THEN @endDate
            ELSE timestampOutOfAlarm
        END 
        AS timestampOutOfAlarm
INTO    #tempTable1
FROM    fctAlarmHistory
WHERE   (timestampOutOfAlarm >= @startDate OR timestampOutOfAlarm = NULL) 
        AND timestamp < @endDate
        AND failureBitValue = 1 
        AND failureBitNr = 't2_13'
        AND fileProjectNr = @projectNr
        And fileProjectMachineNr = @ProjectMachineNr

-- SUM the result of all ON times into OnTime in seconds
SELECT 
    SUM(DATEDIFF("SECOND",
        CASE WHEN timestamp < @startDate 
            THEN @startDate 
            ELSE timestamp 
        END, 
        CASE WHEN timestampOutOfAlarm > @endDate
            THEN @endDate 
            ELSE timestampOutOfAlarm 
        END)) AS OnTime
FROM
    #tempTable1
```

Query for Downtime during ON time:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
SELECT  fctAlarmId,
        fileProjectNr, 
        fileProjectMachineNr, 
        failureBitNr,   
        timestamp, 
        CASE WHEN timestampOutOfAlarm > @endDate OR timestampOutOfAlarm IS NULL 
            THEN @endDate
            ELSE timestampOutOfAlarm
        END 
        AS timestampOutOfAlarm
INTO    #tempTable1
FROM    fctAlarmHistory
WHERE   (timestampOutOfAlarm >= @startDate OR timestampOutOfAlarm = NULL) 
        AND timestamp < @endDate
        AND failureBitValue = 1 
        AND failureBitNr = 't2_13'
        AND fileProjectNr = @projectNr
        And fileProjectMachineNr = @ProjectMachineNr

SELECT  fctAlarmId,
        fileProjectNr, 
        fileProjectMachineNr, 
        failureBitNr,   
        timestamp, 
        CASE WHEN timestampOutOfAlarm > @endDate OR timestampOutOfAlarm IS NULL 
            THEN @endDate
            ELSE timestampOutOfAlarm
        END 
        AS timestampOutOfAlarm
INTO    #tempTable2
FROM    fctAlarmHistory
WHERE   (timestamp BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) 
        AND failureBitValue = 1
        AND (failureBitNr LIKE'f%')
        AND fileProjectNr = @projectNr
        And fileProjectMachineNr = @ProjectMachineNr

CREATE TABLE #tempTable3
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
timestamp datetime,
timestampOutOfAlarm datetime
)

DECLARE failure_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT timestamp, timestampOutOfAlarm
FROM #tempTable2
ORDER BY timestamp ASC

OPEN failure_Cursor

-- Perform the first fetch.
FETCH NEXT FROM failure_Cursor
INTO @rij_timestamp, @rij_timestampOutOfAlarm

INSERT INTO #tempTable3 (timestamp, timestampOutOfAlarm) VALUES(@rij_timestamp,@rij_timestampOutOfAlarm)

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @rij_timestamp
        IF @rij_timestamp <= (SELECT TOP 1 timestampOutOfAlarm FROM #tempTable3 ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
        BEGIN   
            IF @rij_timestampOutOfAlarm > (SELECT TOP 1 timestampOutOfAlarm FROM #tempTable3 ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE #tempTable3 SET timestampOutOfAlarm = @rij_timestampOutOfAlarm WHERE ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM #tempTable3 ORDER BY timestamp DESC)

            END
        END
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO #tempTable3 (timestamp, timestampOutOfAlarm) VALUES(@rij_timestamp,@rij_timestampOutOfAlarm)

        FETCH NEXT FROM failure_Cursor
        INTO @rij_timestamp, @rij_timestampOutOfAlarm
    END
CLOSE failure_Cursor
DEALLOCATE failure_Cursor

-- Select the failure time.
SELECT 
    SUM(DATEDIFF("SECOND",
        CASE WHEN tt3.timestamp < @startDate 
            THEN @startDate 
            ELSE tt3.timestamp 
        END, 
        CASE WHEN tt3.timestampOutOfAlarm > tt1.timestampOutOfAlarm 
            THEN tt1.timestampOutOfAlarm 
            ELSE tt3.timestampOutOfAlarm 
        END)) AS DownTime
FROM
    #tempTable3 tt3
INNER JOIN
    #tempTable1 tt1
ON
    tt3.timestamp BETWEEN tt1.timestamp AND tt1.timestampOutOfAlarm
```